# Android Dream/Screensaver crashing infrequently on some devices

Tags: java, android

I have a livewallpaper application that implements a DreamService following the guide [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/12/daydream-interactive-screen-savers.html) and I am infrequently seeing crash reports come in with the following `ClassCastException` being thrown when it is launched:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4169)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4325)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2574)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8762)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:604)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.service.dreams.DreamService$DreamActivityCallback
  at android.service.dreams.DreamActivity.onCreate (DreamActivity.java:63)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8591)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8570)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1384)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4150)
```

It appears to be only specific Samsung phones causing this, is there anything I can do to fix this, or is this a bug in Samsung code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

History of the changes in [DreamActivity.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commits/main/core/java/android/service/dreams/DreamActivity.java) of AOSP shows this is apparently [a known issue and fixed for Android 14](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/1b33ec13352e72905bedf8d6a75ed6ab3d61f053). In [here](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/f8ebb8da43b7c04a69ec0f7e15f3f99ff9721531) it's explained when this happens,

> The DreamActivity is tied to a DreamService. When the DreamActivity is
> destroyed, so is the DreamService. If the DreamActivity is
> consequently recreated by the WM, this leads to a ClassCastException
> in the DreamActivity.onCreate method.

So given it's already fixed and the situation that was making it is out of reach for regular Android developers I guess there isn't much thing an app developer can or should do.